# Testing devise account_update sanitizer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rspec-rails

After following the Hartl Tutorial I'm trying to change the authentication to use the [devise gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise). My sample application site seems to be working again but some of the specs still fail because some of the routes and user controller actions have changed. So I'm in the process of fixing those and stuck on one that checks to make sure the user can't give themselves admin access.

```
describe "update user with forbidden attributes", type: request do
  FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  let(:params) do 
    { "user[name]" => "new name",
      "user[email]" => user.email,
      "user[current_password]" => user.password,
      "admin" => true }
  end

  before do
    post user_session_path, 'user[email]' => user.email, 'user[password]' => user.password
    patch user_registration_path(user), params
    user.reload
  end

  its(:name) { should eql "new name" } # passes, and should.
  its(:admin?) { should be false } # can't get to fail.
  specify { expect(response).to be_success } # fails, gets response 406.
end
```

This test passes, but it passes because I can't get it to fail. I'm trying to do the usual Red-Green-Refactor and I can't make it go red, even if I add admin to the list of devise acceptable parameters. I want to make sure that this would change admin if the permissions were screwed up.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: devise_controller?
  after_action :print_permitted_parameters, if: devise_controller?

  def configure_permitted_parameters
  ...
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) do |u|
      u.permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password, :admin)
    end
  end

  def print_configured_parameters
    puts "sign_up: " + devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up).join(' ')
      #prints "sign_up: email password password_confirmation"
    puts "sign_in: " + devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in).join(' ')
      #prints "sign_in: email password remember_me"
    puts "account_update: " + devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update).join(' ')
      #prints "account_update: email password password_confirmation current_password"
  end
end
```

The strange thing is that user's name and email do update, so something is working. But the response I get is always 406 for ["Not Acceptable"](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E406.html). So my question is why can I not get the admin tests to fail? And are the 406 errors related?

printing the permitted parameters suggests the parameters aren't being configured for any actions, it's just the default list. And I can sign_in with an existing user but if I just click "sign_in" with no fields it complains of an umpermitted parameter: "remember_me" despite that being on the list. Similarly if I try to sign_up a new user, which used to work, it complains that password_confirmation is unpermitted.

Thanks for your help, I appreciate it.

Comment: Top of my head, what does `devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update)` return?

Comment: @Micahal It's an array, [email, password, password_confirmation, current_password]. Those are the default values. They why does name get updated?

Comment: Maybe you call it before ApplicationController was loaded?

Comment: I may have been, so I changed it to print in an after action, shown above. No dice. Also user sign in/up now complains of unpermitted parameters which it wasn't doing before.

Comment: Thanks to your idea I tried changing the blocks u.permit(stuff) to << stuff and that worked, though I still get response 406.